# The Rapper's Crown?

Tags: cipher, knowledge, liars

You are running through a mysterious dungeon, when you see a large room, which you enter.

Inside there is a man and a woman, one is a **truth teller**, and one a **liar**. However when they write they always tell the **truth**. Behind them are **two** chests, one contains the crown of rappers (good), and the other contains a poisonous snake (very, very bad).

The woman shouts at you "Trust me and use the chest on the **right**!"

The man has lost his voice. He starts making clicking sounds and turning the lights on and off, but you are looking very confused, so he just passes you a note, unfortunately it appears to be in hip-hop-script

The note:

[image: Cipher note]

**Which chest should you open?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Note is Morse Code (Hip Hop script) for

> I
> -
> A
> M
> -
> A
> N
> T
> H
> O
> N
> Y
> -
> R
> A
> Y
> (Hip Hop)

Or

> I am Anthony Ray (Hip Hop)

Which is a reference to

> [Sir-Mix-A-Lot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sir_Mix-a-Lot)

We know that this is true, as they both tell the truth when they write.

So from @Roger's answer:

> I like big butts and **I cannot lie**

So

> The man is the truth-teller and the lady is lying so

You should

> Open the chest on the left

Comment: Well done to @Beastly Gerbil and @Roger!

Comment: You're welcome, glad you enjoed :)

Answer (score 8):

Thanks to @BeastlyGerbil, we know the message translates to:

> I AM ANTHONY RAY (Sir-Mix-a-Lot)

Since we know this to be true, we also know two things about him.

> He likes big butts, and *he cannot lie*.

Therefore,

> He is the truth teller, and the woman is lying, so you should open the chest on the left.

Comment: Oooooh, I see. Well done! Can I add this in my answer?

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Sure!